# CSS3 Bounce then goto link

Tags: jquery

I want to make an img bounce then after the animaton is ready it will navigate to the href
I'm using :target with -webkit-animation: bounce .6s 6 alternate ease-out;

and for the delay to go to link after animation im using (but its delaying the :target aswell)

```
$('.footer a').click(function(e) {
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            e.preventDefault();
            setTimeout(function() { window.location.href = href; }, 3000 );  {   
            };
        });
```

any ideas how to play animation then goto page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After click add class witch will make image bounce.

```
$('#item').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('bounce');
    //other stuff
    //timeout as you do. Becouse you know how long animation is
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you've mentioned `-webkit-animation`, you can use the `webkitAnimationEnd` event:

```
$('.footer a').bind('webkitTransitionEnd', function(e) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    setTimeout(function() { window.location.href = href; }, 3000 );
});
```